# Как задать кастомный шаблон для кастомного типа записи по умолчанию в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть кастомный тип записи tilda.

```
function tilda_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'tilda',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Tilda' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Tilda' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tilda_posttype' );
```

Есть шаблон single-tilda.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Tilda
 * Template Post Type: tilda
 */
```

Ожидал (исходя из иерархии wp), что автоматически, при создании записей этого типа, будет подтягиваться и этот шаблон. Но в реальности его приходится каждый раз выбирать вручную.
Я что-то не так понял про иерархию или что-то не так в коде? Такое вообще возможно реализовать?

[image: Ожидание]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте файл `single-{post-type}.php` (в вашем случае `single-tilda.php`) он и будет шаблоном по умолчанию для кастомного типа постов. Подробнее можете прочитать в иерархии шаблонов: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html